# How do I redirect after a set period of time with HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Tags: html, http, redirect, https, meta

I am creating a website and am trying to redirect to the home page after a set period of time (css animation), I am using http-equiv in a meta tag and it is only redirecting with HTTP, not HTTPS.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3.5;url=home">
```

I have already tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3.5;url=https://(WEBSITE)/home">
```

Comment: When the original request is made via HTTPS, it should make the refresh to HTTPS as well. If the page is accessed via HTTP and you want to redirect to HTTPS, you'll have to write the complete url including https:// as the url parameter.

Comment: @Connum I already tried the code listed above, which is what I think you mean, I get the same result.

Comment: Then it sounds like your server is doing a redirect from https to http, maybe via an .htaccess file or the apache config

Comment: @Connum would I put the file in the directory of the loader or home?

Comment: @Connum and aren't those for apache servers? I am using GitHub pages.

Comment: You didn't specifiy the invironment, so I assumed Apache. ;) Don't know about GitHub pages though, so I'm out!

Comment: I've tried `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3.5;url=https://(WEBSITE)/home">` on my GitHub page and it works as expected. Please visit http://a.testmw.com